# After changes in *.js files, page reloads very slowly (~30sec-2min) [express+gulp+gulp-nodemon+browser-sync]

Tags: express, gulp, browser-sync, nodemon

I am developing application using **express.js**. Also I use **gulp** with **gulp-nodemon** and **browser-sync** to make my development easier and provide auto-updating of ***.js**, ***.html** and ***.css** files of app while i am working on project.

But I have a problem!

When i make changes on ***.css** or ***.html** files auto-updating or auto-reloading are made by **browser-sync** instantly in a few milliseconds. But when i make changes on ***.js** files auto-reloading takes a few minutes. This is a really strange behavior! As i observed when i make changes on ***.js** files **browser-sync** tries to reload a page i am working on fully making **get request** on **localhost:3000**. But this request is pending about 2 minutes and just after that page reloads and new changes are applied.

**Why does it takes so long time to reload a page? And how to solve this problem?Thanks for all your help!**

***Thi is my gulpfile.js***

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync']);

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:3000",
        files: ["public/**/*.*", "views/**/*.*"],
        port: 7000
    });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function(cb){
    var started = false;
    return nodemon({
        script: 'bin/www'
    }).on('start', function() {
        // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
        if (!started) {
            cb();
            started = true;
        }
    });
});
```

***And this is a snapshot of a network section on dev-tools.
Here you can see how long time it takes to reload a page after changes on *.js files***
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WH53.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. So, I tried to change my gulpfile like this:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['nodemon'], function() {

    browserSync.init(null, {
        proxy: "http://localhost:8080",
        //files: ["public/**/*.{css,html,js}"], //Commented
        browser: "google chrome",
        port: 8080
    });

    gulp.watch("public/**/*.{css,html,js}").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

I hope it works with you. Please, take a try.